# get multiple values from an input tag with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to write a code that will generate me several "input" tags to a html

page.

i want to make something like this:

```
<div id="here">
    <input type='text' placeholder='book'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='author'>
</div>
<button id="another-book">+</button>
```

each time that the button is clicked i want to add another input to the page 
right after the previous input.

i do it in a js file with the code:

```
$('#another-book').click(function (e) {
$('#here').append($("<input type='text' placeholder='book'>");
$('#here').append($("<input type='text' placeholder='author'>");
});
```

my problem is that after the user created his inputs and filled them,

i want to get the values of them - for each pair of book and author,

i.e. i want to get in the end a list of pairs (book, author)

how can i do that?

Comment: how do you want the values? as an array?

Comment: and where do you want to get the value? inside that click function?

Comment: as an array is fine.  and in a different click function and in a python file to read the form values

Answer (score 0):

For values of all `input`s in an array

```
$.map($("#here").find("input"),function(o,i){return $(o).val();});
```

**EDIT**

For list of pairs

```
$.map( $("#here").find("input[placeholder='book']"),
    function(o,i){
        var book = $(o).val();
        var author = $(o).next("input[placeholder='author']").val();
        if (book == "" || author == "")
        {
           $(o).remove();
           $(o).next("input[placeholder='author']").remove();
        }
        else
        {
           return { "book": book,
                    "author": author };
        }
     }
);
```

Comment: i tried your code and it worked fine, but i want to add a feature which delete a pair of inputs that didnt fill - i wrote "remove()" instead of the "val
()" but it doesnt work - do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

There is extra `$(` without closing bracket.

this works for me

```
$('#another-book').click(function (e){
    $('#here').append($("<input type='text' placeholder='book'>"));
});
```

**EDIT:**

to get book and author pair use this code from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/527t6qaj/3/)

To get first pair take first element from authors array and first from books.
Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
$('#another-book').click(function(e) {
  console.log($('#here').find('input').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get());
  $('#here').append($("<input type='text' placeholder='book'>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here">
  <input type='text' placeholder='book'>
</div>
<button id="another-book">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('#another-book').click(function (e) {
      
        var a = $('<input>', { text:"", type:"text", placeholder:"book" });
        var b = $('<input>', { text:"", type:"text", placeholder:"author" });
        var c = $('<span>',{}).append(a).append(b);
      
        $('#here').append(c);

   });
    
    
    $('#g-val').click(function(){
      
          var all = [];
    
          $('#here > span').each(function(){
               var $book = [
                  $(this).find('input[placeholder=book]').val() ,
                  $(this).find('input[placeholder=author]').val()
                 ]
               all.push($book);
          });
      
        console.log(all)
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="here">
        <span>
          <input type='text' placeholder='book'>
          <input type='text' placeholder='author'>
        </span>
    </div>



    <button id="another-book">+</button>


    <h4 id="s-value"></h4>


    <button id="g-val">get all input[type=text] ...</button>
```